# checking whether domain of the email compatible with the company name

Tags: php, regex, validation, explode, strpos

I'm trying to implement a code to validate company email. When a user enters company and work email they both should be compatible with each other. As an instance, if a user who's working at QUT registers with the system when he/she enters the company as QUT, then the email domain must be @qut.edu.au. The code below shows the method I've implemented. But for some reason, there is a logical error in the code which gives "You must enter a valid email".(Supposed to be triggered when company name is not included in domain).But it pops up every time it runs. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

```
    <?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/abp/core/init.php';
include 'includes/head.php';
include 'includes/navigation.php';
$email = ((isset($_POST['email']))?sanitize($_POST['email']):'');
$email = trim($email);
$password = ((isset($_POST['password']))?sanitize($_POST['password']):'');
$password = trim($password);
$company_name = ((isset($_POST['company_name']))?sanitize($_POST['company_name']):'');
$company_name = trim($company_name);
$errors = array();
**$domain = array_pop(explode('@', $email));**


if($_POST){
        // form validation
        if(empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
          $errors[] = 'You must provide email and password.';
        }else {
          //validlate email

          **if (strpos( $domain, $company_name) !== true) {**
            $errors[] = 'You must enter a valid email.';


          }else{
            // check if email exist in the databse
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
```

Comment: Maybe you need `stripos`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php Javascript and regex tags seem irrelevant here unless you are looking for other approaches? But what if the company domain doesnt match the name?

Comment: When you use strpos isn't it !== false that you should use? Does `true` work as expected here?

Comment: I'm also curious why you want to force this email and company thing. I work at a company named X but my email is at the more common name Y because of company history. I actually don't think anyone has an email with X at my work or anywhere within the company (it's a very large company)

Comment: Based on what you have now, you want to change your code to `if (stripos($domain, $company_name) === false)`. This will then show the error if the company name is not in the domain. But as @Andreas says, not every company name appears in part or whole in an email domain.

Comment: Hey @Andreas Thanks for your comment. That's a good question. This is one of my client's requirements. He needs to verify user via email because it is more accurate. I'm wondering why don't you have a email with a company domain if it is a "very large company". :)  No idea where you're from. But in Australia, even it is a small company they do have a working email with company domain.

Comment: Also worth considering: spaces and abbreviations. "Frobozz Magic Sofas Corporation" doesn't appear in `fms-corp.com`, for instance…

Comment: @chris85 good point. I've changed it to `stripos`. Still, it's a weak method for validation. Better to use email verification, or compare domain names.

Comment: @fubar Yes, many flaws with this

Comment: @fubar You're a legend. Thanks heaps m8. Good on ya!

Comment: @fubar chris85 I just need to validate the email address of the user as with checking the compatibility of the email with company. So I modified the coding.it still accepts emails with wrong syntax. Help me fams. :)                                                                                                      if (stripos( $domain, $companyname) === false && (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))===false){
      $errors[] = 'You must enter a valid email.';

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in response, morning rush to get to work. Well, I work at the second largest food import and retailer in the country. We have multiple sites all over the country and thousands of employees. Due to company overtakings and buyings the names and emails don't match (and a company management want to use one name for one and the other). We are all employed by X, our email domain is Y, our footer on emails is company X Sweden. And none of it is abbreviated. They are all words. All I'm saying is it's probably not going to works as good as your client thinks.

Comment: I know a Dutch company we had business with last year had the same thing

Comment: @RyanOscar you'd use an `||` instead of an `&&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code reads

```
if(strpos(something, something) !== true) {
    error message
}
```

`strpos` can never ever return `true` only an int or `FALSE`, hence you always get an error message. it's in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-returnvalues) too.

the correct version would be:

```
if(strpos($haystack, $needle) === false) {
     //errormessage
}
```

(additionally the concept of matching an email address to a company name is not a good idea as mentioned abundantly in the comments)

Comment: You can kind of use true but as you say strpos returns a position and thus have a built in error for this matter. https://3v4l.org/h6IY9 Here it returns "yes" as in true. But if you search for "hello" then the position will be 0, and 0 in a if() will be false even though the condition is true. What you can do to fix this is to add a blank space as the first char in string `strpos(" " . $str, ....);` this makes sure 0 can't be returned even if it's true

Comment: But you are correct in that it's a bad idea to even think about this kind of code. It will only create problems. If I as a customer could not create an account because my email does not match my company I would click the "back" button and return to my Google search.

Comment: @Andreas I didn't provide the solution, I just say, that strpos can never return true, and since `===` (or `!==`) do include a type comparison, the error message is always output. The actual answer is "`=== false`" since it does exactly what is necessary here, because `0 !== false`.

Comment: Andreas Dunnno why you're so obsessed with this idea. Get over it. It's all about how to implement it. not about how convenient it is. Thanks for your answer @Jakumi. Thanks everyone!